# how to get mouse location once but dont return and until I get the mouse location twice in napari using python

Tags: python, mouse, python-napari

I am writing on a napari plugin. I have the following to retrieve mouse location

```
img = cv2.imread("../medium/24708.1_4 at 20X.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
viewer = napari.view_image(img)
layer = viewer
@layer.mouse_drag_callbacks.append
def callback(layer, event):  # (0,0) is the center of the upper left pixel
     x,y = viewer.cursor.position
     print(x,y)
```

but this will print the mouse location immediately after I click. I want to get the mouse location once I click but dont print it until I click the mouse again, which means I want to print the mouse position twice at once.
I tried loops, but it just return same mouse location.

```
@layer.mouse_drag_callbacks.append
def callback(layer, event):  # (0,0) is the center of the upper left pixel
i=1
arr=[]
while i<=2:
    x,y = viewer.cursor.position
    x = round(x)
    y = round(y)
    arr.append(x)
    arr.append(y)
    i += 1
print(arr)
[1376, 691, 1376, 691]
[1506, 1117, 1506, 1117]
[1575, 826, 1575, 826]
```

Comment: So what do you want to happen if you click the mouse a third time?

Comment: I am trying to use few points to extract the cell in a 2d image, so if the image cannot be extract by only one point, I need two points. If it cannot be extract by two points, I need three points ..etc, so I want the same print three mouse positions at once if I have to use three points to extract a cell

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to `print()` the points, but to save the points in a collection?

Comment: yes, thats what I want, I tried while loop, but It just save same mouse location

Comment: Why don't you use an array of `tuples`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are going to do with the points, or what how you are going to decide how many are needed, but you will need to collect the points. A `list` seems to fit the bill:

```py
points = []

@layer.mouse_drag_callbacks.append
def callback(layer, event):  # (0,0) is the center of the upper left pixel
     points.append(viewer.cursor.position)
```

Comment: This did save mouse location, but how I get this "points" list from the callback function? I shouldnt do the next operation within callback function.

Comment: What `"callback function"` are you referring to? In my answer above I show how the callback collects `position` values into `points`.

Comment: I mean the def callback(layer, event): will keep appending mouse location to points list, but how can I get this list after the length of list is 2 from the def callback? I tried to set the points as global variable but it doesnt work

Comment: `if len(points) >= 2:`?